# How do you configure Role Based authentication in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have an MVC application that I'm porting.  It uses just a simple Role Provider to determine a user's role in the application.  In past versions, you would just reference the providers like so:

```
 <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

There's no web.config in .NET Core, so how would you provide the same functionality in .NET Core?

Comment: You need to reference your provider in `ConfigureServices` method on your `Startup` class... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: Thank you, but that example has a heavy mix of EF and doesn't seem to work.  I don't need a login screen, I just need the roles of the already logged in user.